# Unexpected return value error - Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm creating a class that is basically practice with Array usage in Java and programming, and I need to make an array of 40 random integers between the number 1-6(inclusive). However, my code will not compile because of an "unexpected return value" error. How can I fix this? code below:

```
public class LongestRun
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("\f");

        int[] values = new int[40];
        int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
        int count ;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = randNum;
            return values[i];
        }


    }}
```

Comment: you are returning inside a `for` loop and main doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Also I was confused because I swore it was possible to return inside a for loop.

Comment: you actually can but why would you? imagine you want a for loop to iterate 10 times, if you return after every iteration, you get out that for loop the first time it iterates, not ideal really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` doesn't have a return value (`void`), so you cannot return a value from it (`return` statement). You'd likely want to `print()` the result instead.

Also, to get 40 random numbers, you'd want to move the `random()` call inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: My answer is wrong, would only apply if your return type would not be `void`, sorry.

You need to have a return statement outside the for-loop.

If you don't have a return statement outside a conditional loop/case, java will not compile.

So in your case your could would have to look like the following:

```
public class LongestRun
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("\f");

    int[] values = new int[40];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
        values[i] = randNum;
    }

   return values[i];


}
}
```

Comment: Still won't compile, because you're trying to return a value from a `void` method.